# BTOUCH:error BI1017:Do not know how to make a signature for System.Int32* in method get_IssueTransport

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, objective-sharpie, xamarin.ios-binding, xamarin-binding

I am binding JMC objective C static library to Xamarin compatible one, currently I am trying to build my binding project now(which contains ApiDefinition.cs, StructsAndEnums.cs and libJmcSDK.a) but when I try to build this Xamarin binding project I'm getting the following error:
**BTOUCH: error BI1017: btouch: Do not know how to make a signature for System.Int32* in method 'get_IssueTransport'**.

When I try to search for get_IssueTransport method, their is no search results for this, trying to find the System.Int32 signature as well but not able to find in throughout solution.

Any help in resolving this issue is much appreciated in advance. Thanks.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

#### Answer

Remove **unsafe** keyword and * from int.

#### Like:

> <strike>unsafe</strike> int<strike>*</strike>

Answer (score 1):

Change `int*` (any pointer type) to `IntPtr`